# Getting a bad access error in merge sort

Tags: c++, mergesort

The error related to a bad access pops up when I run my implementation of merge sort. Is there something wrong with my logic or I am I using memory in an incorrect way somewhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> mergeIt(vector<int> l, vector<int> r);
void print(const vector<int> &vec);

vector<int> mergesort(vector<int> arr, int lo, int high) {
  if(arr.size() <= 1) return arr;

  int mid = lo + (high-lo)/2;
  vector<int> b(mid);
  vector<int> c(high-mid);

  for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
    b.push_back(arr[i]);
  }
  for(int i = mid; i < high; i++)
    c.push_back(arr[i]);

  vector<int>sb = mergesort(b,lo,high/2);
  vector<int>sc = mergesort(c,mid,high);
   print(sb);
   print(sc);
   return mergeIt(sb,sc);
}

vector<int> mergeIt(vector<int> l, vector<int> r) {
  vector<int> p(l.size()+r.size());
  int li=0, ri=0, pi = 0;

  while(li < l.size() && ri < r.size()) {
      if(l[li] <= r[ri])
    p[pi++] = l[li++];
      else if(l[li] > r[ri])
    p[pi++]= r[ri++];
  }
  //add in the rest of elements if they have not been added yet
  if(li < l.size()) {
    for(int i = li; i < l.size(); i++) p[pi++] = l[i];
  }
  else{
    for(int i = ri; i < r.size(); i++) p[pi++] = r[i];
  }
  return p;
}

vector<int> mergesort(vector<int> arr) {
    int lo = 0;
    int high = arr.size();
    return mergesort(arr,lo,high);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //test client
  vector<int> nums;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    nums.push_back(rand()%10+1);
  }
  vector<int> p = mergesort(nums);
  for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) cout << p[i];
  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get when I try to debug my program with lldb:

```
Process 369 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x14fe, 0x00007fff8d9c4297 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 20, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3fffb4)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8d9c4297 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 20
libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 20:
-> 0x7fff8d9c4297:  movl   %edx, -0xac(%rbp)
   0x7fff8d9c429d:  movq   %rsi, %r14
   0x7fff8d9c42a0:  movq   %rdi, %r12
   0x7fff8d9c42a3:  movq   %r12, -0x68(%rbp)
```

Please help as I am a beginner to C++ and am not very experienced with handling errors at runtime.

Comment: The way you're doing this, I see no reason for `lo` and `high` *at all*. You're already partitioning into subvectors and recursing. the vectors are your partitions; `lo` and `high` are useless.

Comment: You essentially are asking the community to debug your issue for you. You should do this yourself, narrow down the issue and then ask people for specific issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one problem.

Here you build two vectors, one of mid elements, the other high-mid. Since you layer fill them with push_back you should build them empty (using default constructor)

```
  vector<int> b(mid);
  vector<int> c(high-mid);
```

then

```
vector<int>sb = mergesort(b,lo,high/2);
vector<int>sc = mergesort(c,mid,high);
```

here since you sort the full vector, you do not need to pass the indexes (which are wrong). You can run your algorithm on the range (0, vector.size()) and get rid of those two integers.

Then you are better of learning how to use the debugger. There may be some other problem that I missed.

Comment: I would rather suggest to initialize them with desired capacity and size and then not to use `push_back` but assignment.

Comment: @tobi303 funny that. I was about to suggest just using the iterator-pair constructor of std::vector and thusly *both* sizing and initializing the subvectors. I.e. something [like this](http://ideone.com/FDRAa2).